# what does chord "Co" or "Fo" etc., mean on an accordion

Tags: notation, sheet-music

I took accordion lessons 50 years ago, and now I'm trying to re learn everything.

Comment: On the actual accordion, are the "o" actually little circles that are in the upper right, like a degree sign?

Answer (score 3):

In the following, *lowercase* chord names stand for actual accordion chord buttons, uppercase names are either regular chord names or single notes.

c° is also known as cdim, the diminished chord.  It's A-C-E♭.  The actual inversion depends on where the Stradella chord octave is located.  This isn't a full diminished chord, of course, but it is nevertheless called that on the accordion.  If you add the proper fifth by playing the two buttons c°+cm, you actually get the chord Cm6.

It's little-known that on accordions with just three chord rows (because of three bass rows and/or a Belgian system, or just five rows anyway) the *seventh* row isn't F7=E♭-F-A but rather E♭-A-C which is functionally indistinguishable in typical counterbass play involving the F bass button.

So if you don't have a diminished chord row, play f7 instead of c°, b♭7 instead of f°, and c7 instead of g°.  That will be *exactly* accurate.

Russian 6-row bass bayans actually put the c° chord in the same row as F, making for A-F-f-fm-f7-c° .  That makes it easy to press f7 and c° with the same finger in case you need the full F7 *with* the fifth included.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this would be written as a superscript 0 like a degree mark as mentioned above. So you are looking at C° or F°. This represents a diminished 7th chord (missing the fifth). On a Stradella bass accordion, this would be the sixth row.

C° (accordion) would be the notes C, Eb, and A. Stradella bass skips the fifth in the Dominant 7th and diminished 7th chords (to keep the sound balances with the three-note major and minor chords.) The missing F# (or Gb) can be filled by the right hand.

Comment: Is that really a C diminished 7th chord? I thought a fully diminished 7th would be Bbb which is also A natural.

Comment: Also no idea what you’re talking about with an Italian augmented sixth. I don’t see any connection between either the incorrect C, Eb, Ab you suggest or the C, Eb, A (Bbb) that actually happens on accordion C°.

Comment: My mistake. It is a C, Eb, A chord. The Italian Sixth is the Dominant Seventh (C-E-A# enharmonically C-E-Bb). (I just noticed I described this better for another question.)

Comment: I'm actually disappointed that it's not also/actually the Italian 6th. That would be cool. But maybe not as useful as a diminished 7th. Note that fully diminished 7th chords are root ambiguous (allowing for inversion). In other words, Cdim7, Ebdim7, Gbdim7, and Adim7 all are made up of exactly those four notes.